# 3-D evaluations of a triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

We all do evaluations of triangles on 2-D space based on the fact that the sum of its internal angles is 180 degree. When we draw a triangle on a sphere this sum changes and gets bigger than 180 degree. I was thinking if we know the eccentricity value of that sphere could we consider that value while doing the same evaluations?